# C# WPF Getting Incorrect Transform Bound information?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, transform, bounds

I'm creating a tile matching game, where a player drags tiles onto tile holders, and earns points if the correct tile is placed. See the below image for reference:

[tile match game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1UCk.png)

I am using the ScatterView control, from Microsoft.Surface.Presentation as a board to hold my tiles, along with the ScatterViewItems, as the tiles themselves.

I want to be able to drop ScatterViewItems onto the holders, and for that corresponding holder to assess whether it can accept the tile which was dropped on it.

I have managed to get a lot of the information I need, however the transform bounds information I am getting from my tile holders is skewed?

I am using touch up event, and rect contains/ intersectswith methods, however I am getting incorrect results about the tile holder. Whilst many results are close, they are all slightly out. I've tried drawing my 'rects' to a canvas, however it shows the correct points and dimensions.

I was initially rotating some of my controls, as I need them to be along the side of the board, however stopped this, as thought it was to blame, however the results are still wrong. You will notice (if you get the solution zip), that on some holders, the bounds will not register correctly, whilst sometimes when not over a holder (just nearby) it will. I think the rect bounds I'm using are incorrect, but I cannot see the error! Would really appreciate any help.

Here's a link to a zip of the solution (VS2015): [project solution as zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2d9w_QUl6HISS1jbi1LVXAtOEk)

Here's the code used in the main, if you would prefer:

```
using Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Controls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace TestingSVI_Intersection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate () { };
        StackPanel[] stacks = new StackPanel[4];
        Vector tileSize = new Vector(60, 80);
        Vector holderSize = new Vector(0, 0);
        Vector gameGridSize = new Vector(0, 0);
        int numberOfLetters = 5;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Svi_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ScatterViewItem svi = e.Source as ScatterViewItem;
            Point p1 = svi.TransformToAncestor(MiddleGrid).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

            Rect r1 = new Rect(p1.X, p1.Y, svi.ActualWidth, svi.ActualHeight);
            Console.WriteLine($"SVI at: {svi.ActualCenter}");

            Rectangle rectangle;

            foreach (StackPanel panel in stacks)
            {
                foreach (UserControl holder in panel.Children)
                {

                    Point p2 = holder.TransformToAncestor(MiddleGrid).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

                    Rect r2 = new Rect(p2.X, p2.Y, holder.ActualWidth, holder.ActualHeight);
                    rectangle = new Rectangle();
                    rectangle.Width = holder.Width;
                    rectangle.Height = holder.Height;
                    Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, p2.X);
                    Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, p2.Y);
                    rectangle.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SpringGreen);
                    rectangle.StrokeThickness = 1;
                    canvasMe.Children.Add(rectangle);

                    if (r2.IntersectsWith(r1) == true)
                    {
                        if (r2.Contains(p1))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Intersection at: {holder.Name}");
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void IntersectionFound(ScatterViewItem svi, UserControl uC)
        {

        }

        //private void Svi_PreviewTouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    ScatterViewItem svi = e.Source as ScatterViewItem;
        //    Point p1 = svi.TransformToAncestor(mainGrid).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

        //    Rect r1 = new Rect(p1.X, p1.Y, svi.ActualWidth, svi.ActualHeight);
        //    Console.WriteLine($"SVI at: {svi.ActualCenter}");
        //    foreach (StackPanel panel in stacks)
        //    {
        //        foreach (UserControl holder in panel.Children)
        //        {

        //            Point p2 = holder.TransformToAncestor(mainGrid).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

        //            Rect r2 = new Rect(p2.X, p2.Y, holder.ActualWidth, holder.ActualHeight);

        //            Console.WriteLine($"Checked: {holder.Name} at centre: ({p2.X + holder.Width / 2}, {p2.Y + holder.Height / 2})");

        //            //if (r1.IntersectsWith(r2) == true)
        //            //{

        //            //    Console.WriteLine($"Intersection at: {holder.Name}");
        //            //}
        //            if (r2.Contains(r1) == true)
        //            {
        //                Console.WriteLine($"Intersection at: {holder.Name}");
        //            }
        //        }
        //    }
        //}

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (stacks[3] != null)
            {
                foreach (StackPanel panel in stacks)
                {
                    panel.Children.Clear();
                }

                canvasMe.Children.Clear();
                scatterView.Items.Clear();
            }
            gameGridSize.X = MiddleGrid.ActualWidth;
            gameGridSize.Y = MiddleGrid.ActualHeight;

            holderSize.X = gameGridSize.X * 0.10f;
            holderSize.Y = gameGridSize.Y * 0.15f;

            stacks[0] = letterHolders1;
            stacks[1] = letterHolders2;
            stacks[2] = letterHolders3;
            stacks[3] = letterHolders4;

            int count = 0;
            foreach (StackPanel panel in stacks)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLetters; i++)
                {
                    UserControl uC = new UserControl
                    {
                        Width = holderSize.X,
                        Height = holderSize.Y,
                        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                        BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
                        BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow),
                        Name = $"UC_{count.ToString()}"
                    };

                    count++;

                    if (panel == stacks[1] || panel == stacks[2])
                    {
                        //uC.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(90);
                        uC.Width = holderSize.Y;
                        uC.Height = holderSize.X;
                    }
                    panel.Children.Add(uC);
                }
            }

            MiddleGrid.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);

            Console.WriteLine($"Stack 2: ({letterHolders2.ActualWidth}, {letterHolders2.ActualHeight})");

            holderSize.X = letterHolders2.ActualHeight / numberOfLetters;

            tileSize.X = holderSize.X * 0.8f;
            tileSize.Y = holderSize.Y * 0.8f;

            foreach (StackPanel panel in stacks)
            {
                foreach (UserControl control in panel.Children)
                {
                    control.Width = holderSize.X;
                    control.Height = holderSize.Y;

                    if (panel == stacks[1] || panel == stacks[2])
                    {
                        control.Width = holderSize.Y;
                        control.Height = holderSize.X;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                ScatterViewItem svi = new ScatterViewItem
                {
                    Width = tileSize.X,
                    MinWidth = tileSize.X,
                    MaxWidth = tileSize.X,
                    Height = tileSize.Y,
                    MinHeight = tileSize.Y,
                    MaxHeight = tileSize.Y,
                    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),

                };

                //svi.PreviewTouchUp += Svi_PreviewTouchUp;
                svi.PreviewMouseUp += Svi_PreviewMouseUp;

                scatterView.Items.Add(svi);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And it's corresponding XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestingSVI_Intersection.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestingSVI_Intersection"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="70"/>
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="70"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid Background="Black" Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition  Height="64"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition  Height="64"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="Gray"/>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1"/>
                <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="Gray"/>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Background="Black" Grid.Column="2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition  Height="64"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition  Height="64"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="Gray"/>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Button x:Name="startButton" Content="Start" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Blue" Foreground="White" Click="Button_Click"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="Gray"/>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MiddleGrid">
                <Grid x:Name="GameGrid">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.6*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.6*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel x:Name="letterHolders1" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">

                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel x:Name="letterHolders2" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel x:Name="letterHolders3" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel x:Name="letterHolders4" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">

                    </StackPanel>


                </Grid>
                <s:ScatterView x:Name="scatterView">

                </s:ScatterView>

                <Canvas x:Name="canvasMe" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It's been a long time so I don't remember the specific API names anymore but there is a Puzzle sample app in the Surface SDK that will demo how to do this with ScatterView

Comment: I will take a look, and pass back anything I find. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RobertLevy Thanks, I managed to take a look at the Puzzle sample, and noticed it's use of Rect.Intersects, so I adapted mine to be somewhat similar, and got an OK result. Please see update, as am so close. I really appreciate your help :)